Upgrade sdk version from 33 to 35 for android in react native project
When trying to upgrade the android sdk version from 33 to 35 within a react native project. The project fails to build. Here is the Error:
node_modules\react-native-gradle-plugin\src\main\kotlin\com\facebook\react\TaskConfiguration.kt: (114, 12): Class 'kotlin.Unit' was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.
I follow these 4 steps and encounter the error:

Build.gradle (Android) I have changed the values to:
compileSdkVersion = 35
targetSdkVersion = 35

Build.gradle (Android) I have upgraded gradle like so:
classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1")


3.gradle-wrapper.properties I have upgraded gradle to 8.0 like so:
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-all.zip

In the package.json here are the versions of react:
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-native": "0.70.2"

When I try to upgrade react native this also fails and I believe this is because I have added other dependencies like firestore which stop a successful upgrade however I can't remove these dependecies for the the upgrade as they are needed very much.
How can I upgrade from sdk 33 to 35 for android in a react native project given the information above???
